# Use Google Calendar in a Phonegap App

Tags: cordova, synchronization, google-calendar-api

I need to synchronize my Google Calendar account in my phonegap application, I want the app to read what I have in my Google Calendar, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just try embedding it? Not sure how well it will look on a mobile form factor, but Google Calendars support iframe embedding. I'd try it and see.